# Migrating an Application Server to another newly-introduced Server to the Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Recently, it occured that out SharePoint Server Farm would have to undergo OS Upgrade, specifically from 2012 to 2012 r2.
Searching through the internet, it made it clear that in-place upgrades are off the question, and that the best way of action in such circumstances would be, the introduction of an 2012 R2 Application Server and migration of Services and Web-Application to the new Server.

Unfortunately, i cannot find any material on such migration tasks. I do not wish to restore the Farm on another Farm. Can't i simply, introduce an App server to the farm, switch everything over to it and afterwards remove the old server from the farm?

Thanks in advance for your time and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this with 2010.  We transitioned from 08r2 to 2012r2  All you have to do is add the new servers to the farm. Change your DNS entries to the new web server IP. And then remove the old servers from the farm.  There is a little more to it than that if you have customizations or extra non-SharePoint sites or processes.

If you run into difficulties, you just have to add the old server back to the farm.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It's a SharePoint Farm Deployment that just has an Application Server and a Database Server, one Web Application, which serves different site collections that are build with the Document Center template.
No search service is enabled and no customizations deployed, other than the User Profile Service that should be migrated.

Comment: So from what you are saying is that i should:
1) introduce a newly created 2012 R2 server with SharePoint deployed
2) remove the old 2012 server from the farm
Am i getting this correctly?
I am currently trying to perform such tasks in a test environment.

Comment: Yes.  That is the supported path.  You just, temporarily, have a larger farm with mixed OS.  When you add a server, all the services and needed files are copied to it as part of the joining process.  Make sure you host Central Admin on the new Web server.

Comment: I ticked the option that showed that the server would host the central administration, right before joining the server to the farm through the SharePoint configuration step... If that's what you mean... Shouldn't all the alternate access mappings be restored ? It just sounds like a really task...

Comment: Yes.  AAMs and any other SharePoint settings will be replicated to the new server.  Any SSL Certs and things outside SharePoint will not.

Comment: I tried it with an evaluation trial version and it worked!
lost a day or two, trying to setup sharepoint on a Windows 2012 R2 machine, but got it done after all... 
thanks for the help !